# Why doesn't Graphics[{Point[sdata]}] plot the last two points in sdata?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I am combining the plot of 1/x with some of the points on that line.
Here is the data

```
sdata = { {-5, -0.2}, {-2, -0.5}, {-1, -1}, {-1/2, -2}, {-0.2, -5}, 
          {0.2, 5}, {0.5, 2}, {1, 1}, {2.0, 0.5}, {5.0, 0.2} }
```

This graphs all ten points.

```
ListPlot[{sdata}, Joined -> False]
```

When I use Show to combine the Plot of 1/x with the Graphics, it works great except the last two points don't appear.

```
Show[
     Plot[{0 , 1/x}, {x, -7, 7}, PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-7, 7}}], 
     Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], Blue, Point[sdata]}]
     ]
```

How do I get the last two points to show up?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Can you please let us know which version of Mathematica you are using? Also, a screenshot would help. For example, I see [all ten points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tM8p.png) in v12.3.

Comment: You could also just use `Plot` with `Epilog`, e.g., `Plot[{0, 1/x}, {x, -7, 7}, PlotRange -> {{-7, 7}, {-7, 7}}, Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Blue, Point[sdata]}]`

Comment: Add `,PlotRange -> All` after `Graphics[..]` before the last `]`. `Show[]` uses the settings from the first plot. It does not try to combine the options.

Comment: I am using 13.3.1.0. Screenshot follows:

Comment: When preparing to include a screenshot, I found that all the points are plotting now. I had left the application on all night. I didn't change anything, but now it graphs with all points showing. Thanks for whatever you guys did - or thanks to the Mathematica gremlins. My mind is blown.